# display the records with status "completed = true" using the selector in angular

Tags: angular

Initially my all the record with status true & false should display ,and upon using the condition in selector,it should show record with completed= true . How to use an input condition in selector, that it should show the record only "with completed = true"?
please find the example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-tt1nwd?file=app%2Fdropdown.component.ts

Comment: Please format your question with sections. 'Issue', 'Code', 'Expected output' etc

Answer (score 0):

You were having this code in dropdown.completed.ts

```
this.titles = this.displaytitle.filter(s => s.completed === 'true');
```

But completed is a boolean not string. you should replace it with :-

```
this.titles = this.displaytitle.filter(s => s.completed);
```

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-pafiw2?file=app/dropdown.component.ts

Comment: Initially my all the record with status true & false should display ,and upon using the condition in selector<appDropdown>,it should show record with completed= true

Comment: you didn't mention any of that in your question. make your question more clear.

Comment: also your comment doesn't talk about what is condition here.